# scala error: class type required but T found

Tags: scala, generics, slick, generic-programming, slick-3.0

I'm trying to create a generic abstract class table and create a generic `TableQuery` using it with `slick`

The generic Table:

```scala
trait TaskRow {
  def dvProjectId: Int
  def timestamp: Long
  def status: String
}

abstract class TaskTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag, name) {
  def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("Id")
  def status: Rep[String] = column[String]("Status")
}
```

Usage:

```scala
case class ATaskRow(id: Int, status: String) extends TaskRow

class ATaskTable(tag: Tag) extends TaskTable[ATaskRow](tag, "A") {
  def * : ProvenShape[ATaskRow] = (id, status) <> (ATaskRow.tupled, ATaskRow.unapply)
}
```

```
class Repo[T <: TaskTable[R], R <: TaskRow] @Inject()(db: DB) {
  ...

  private def table: TableQuery[T] = TableQuery[T]
}
```

this line gives an error - `class type required but T found`:

`private def table: TableQuery[T] = TableQuery[T]`

There's a way I can fix it?

Comment: T is not a class type, but a type parameter. Could you try adding a ClassTag typeclass instance for T? E.g. `class Repo[T <: TaskTable[R] : ClassTag`

Comment: @slouc I tried to add this and it still gives the same error

Comment: Sry, then I can't help much bcs I don't know anything about Slick. Maybe you can provide an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that doesn't involve external libraries? Otherwise I'd have to dig around Slick repo to check what kind of `apply` method the `TableQuery` object has etc.

Comment: Can you explain what that `def` is supposed to do? You probably need to show how `table` will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this.

```scala
class ARepo @Inject()(db: DB)
  extends Repo[ATaskTable, ATaskRow](db, (tag: Tag) => new ATaskTable(tag))

class Repo[T <: TaskTable[R], R <: TaskRow] (db: DB, cons: Tag => T) {
  ...

  private def table: TableQuery[T] = TableQuery(cons)
}
```